# html input width wont change

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im using bootstrap 3 and in here when i set the input width to 100% it won't fill the whole column width by the textbox. I even tried textarea but that also has the same issue that the width won't increase after given length.

```
<div class="container body-content" >

   < form name="mainForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post" >

     < div class="row" >
            < div class="col-sm-2"><label>Main Category : </label></div >
            < div class="col-sm-6"><input spellcheck="true" ng-disabled="editVM.FirstLevel.ID > 0" type="text" style="font-size:15px; width:100%;" class="form-control" id="Main_Cat" ng-model="editVM.FirstLevel.Name">< /div>
            < div class="col-sm-4"></div >
     < /div>
```

Comment: did you try using `!important` property in width.

Comment: no can you explain how to set it.

Comment: `style="font-size:15px; width:100% !important;"`

Comment: make sure your col-sm-6 is working fine

Comment: col-sm-6 is working fine i added this code and the div background color worked fine                                                                                                 <div class="col-sm-6"><div style="background-color:aqua;">Hello</div></div>

Answer (score -1):

You could try to set **style="font-size:15px; width:100%;box-sizing: border-box;"**
And also set padding of its container (div element) to zero.

Comment: @Kandekumbura: in which browser are you using to comfirm?

Comment: im using chrome

Comment: I try your code at link https://jsfiddle.net/bgfumhpe/  and confirm it on Chrome. The input seem to fill entire column, isn't it?